# MD5 hash discrepancy between Python and PHP?

Tags: php, python, md5

I'm trying to create a checksum of a binary file (flv/f4v, etc) to verify the contents of the file between the server and client computers. The application that's running on the client computer is python-based, while the server is using PHP.

PHP code is as follows:

```
$fh = fopen($filepath, 'rb');
$contents = fread($fh, filesize($filepath));
$checksum = md5(base64_encode($contents));
fclose($fh);
```

Python code is as follows:

```
def _get_md5(filepath):
    fh = open(filepath, 'rb')
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    md5.update(f.read().encode('base64'))
    checksum = md5.hexdigest()
    f.close()
    return checksum
```

on the particular file I'm testing, the PHP and Python md5 hash strings are as follows, respectively:

```
cfad0d835eb88e5342e843402cc42764
0a96e9cc3bb0354d783dfcb729248ce0
```

Server is running CentOS, while the client is a MacOSX environment. I would greatly appreciate any help in understanding why the two are generating different hash results, or if it something I overlooked (I am relatively new to Python...). Thank you!

*[post mortem: the problem was ultimately the difference between Python and PHP's base64 encoding varieties. MD5 works the same between the two scripting platforms (at least using .hexdigest() in Python).]*

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the base64 representation of the file is different, not the md5 algorithm, can you check that?

Comment: Why bother with base64 at all?  Why not just md5 the raw binary?

Comment: Any reason you're base64-encoding the file's contents first? The md5 functions will happily chug away on raw binary data too. As htf suggests, remove base64 from the equation and see what happens. If, for whatever reason, python and php line wrap the base64 data (e.g. for email insertion), and chose a different wrap point, that'd throw off the hash and you'd never know because you're not checking the base64 output for equality first.

Comment: Thank you all for the very prompt responses! I stripped the base64 encoding step, and it seems to be working perfectly across the board now. I'm not even sure why I used base64 encoding in the first place, I suppose I might have done it in an attempt to normalize the content, which it inevitably ended up making worse, haha. Issues are resolved! Thank you!

Comment: @user715565 The way to mark a question as "resolved" on SO is to Accept the answer that best solves the issue (click the checkmark under the answer's score)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would rather assume that the base64 implementations differ.

**EDIT**

PHP:

```
php -r 'var_dump(base64_encode(str_repeat("x", 10)));'
string(16) "eHh4eHh4eHh4eA=="
```

Python (Note the trailing newline):

```
>>> ("x" * 10).encode('base64')
'eHh4eHh4eHh4eA==\n'
```

Comment: And the comments to the question bring up another important point: You don't need base64, if you want a hash, you can hash the string directly.

Answer (score 14):

PHP and python use different base64 flavors:

- [PHP's base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) uses [MIME (RFC 2045, see page 24)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt)
- [Python's base64 module](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html) uses [RFC 3548](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3548.txt).

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be that your base-64-encoding the file data, changing the structure of the binary data, in php I *belive* that it does not base_64 encode the file.

Give this a go:

```
def md5_file(filename):
    //MD5 Object
    crc = hashlib.md5()
    //File Pointer Object
    fp = open(filename, 'rb')

    //Loop the File to update the hash checksum
    for i in fp:
        crc.update(i)

    //Close the resource
    fp.close()

    //Return the hash
    return crc.hexdigest()
```

and within PHP use `md5_file` and see if that works accordingly.

python taken from: http://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.md5-file/

Answer (score 4):

Python appends a newline '\n' to the string when using .encode, therefore the input strings to the md5 function are different. [This](http://bugs.python.org/issue10970) issue in the Python bug tracker explains it in detail. See below for the gist of it:

```
>>> import base64
>>> s='I am a string'
>>> s.encode('base64')
'SSBhbSBhIHN0cmluZw==\n'
>>> base64.b64encode(s)
'SSBhbSBhIHN0cmluZw=='
>>> s.encode('base64')== base64.b64encode(s)+'\n'
True
```